Create function arguments from a character vector
Using the rlang package, I can create a function with the following expression:
new_function(pairlist2(a = , b = ), quote(a * b))

Imagine that I have a & b in a character vector:
arg_names <- c("a", "b")

How could I use arg_names to create the function arguments?
It's important to mention that I don't know the number of parameters beforehand. Another procedure returns the parameters, which can vary.

How do you intend to have the body of your function recognize all the input argument names?   Your question looks like the easy part of the problem.

There is already a good answer but since the question did use the rlang tag we can use the rlang missing_arg function.  We will extract the variables from the body to get the arguments and assume they are in the order encountered but we could supply args <- c("a", "b") if that were preferable.
library(purrr)
library(rlang)

# input
f <- function() a * b

args <- all.vars(body(f)) # or use args <- c("a","b")
formals(f) <- map(set_names(args), ~ missing_arg())

f
## function (a, b) 
## a * b

The corresponding base R code would be:
formals(f) <- sapply(args, \(x) unname(alist(x=)))


You can use setNames(). So you can write the following:
argnames <- c("a", "b")
args <- setNames(replicate(length(argnames), quote(expr = )), argnames)

It’s worth noting that quote(expr = ) behaves extremely weirdly! The above works, but the following — which should be equivalent — does unfortunately not work:
empty_arg <- quote(expr = )
args <- setNames(replicate(length(argnames), empty_arg), argnames)

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  argument "empty_arg" is missing, with no default

(I confess that I don’t understand exactly why R behaves this way, and I suspect that this is a subtle evaluation bug.)

Thanks. What if I don't know beforehand the number of arguments? I should have clarified that in the original post.

@jandraor Ah that makes it more complicated (although the solution is still setNames()). However, more importantly, how are you going to use those arguments? I.e. how are you constructing the function body?

That's not a concern. In short, the body is also adjusted based on the number of parameters. My main concern is supplying new_function with dynamic arguments.

@jandraor Fair enough! See the updated answer, that should do the trick.

Without rlang, employing body and formals for the task.
> fn <- \(a, b) {
+   `body<-`(`formals<-`(\() {}, v=setNames(vector('list', length(a)), a)), v=b)
+ }
> FUN <- fn(c("a", "b", "c"), quote(a*b - c))
> FUN
function (a = NULL, b = NULL, c = NULL) 
a * b - c
<environment: 0x6384c6469388>
> FUN(7, 8, 14)
[1] 42

We could also just provide the body.
> fnn <- \(b) {
+   a <- all.vars(b)
+   `body<-`(`formals<-`(\() {}, v=setNames(vector('list', length(a)), a)), v=b)
+ }
> fnn(quote(a*b - c))(7, 8, 14)
[1] 42

